# managing array prop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a react application, and i've found a bug where i'm filtering an array for searching the current item the user has selected and then i'm going to do stuff with it...but, didn't know that filter function return a reference to the array's item, so, every change i made to the selected item i'm doing the same to the prop array.

```
const pippo = maledettoArray.filter(item => item.id === idInfame)[0];
```

How can i filter the prop array to get the specific item without changing it?

Comment: You're not changing item in the code you posted. Consider posting all relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` method instead of `filter` which returns first match and exits the loop.

```
const pippo = maledettoArray.find(item => item.id === idInfame)
```

To create shallow copy of the object you can use `Object.assign` or spread syntax.

```
const clone = {...pipo}
```

If you want to create deep copy of the nested object then you could use Lodash `_.cloneDeep(value)` method.

Comment: looks like also find function is doing the same:  if i do pippo.id = 100 then also the maledettoArray item will have 100

Comment: Yes because objects are passed by reference so if you want to modify the result you need to create a copy.

Comment: Note that {...obj} creates just a shallow copy, so if you have nested objects and modify some of its properties you still change the original.

Comment: and in case of nested object?

Comment: Use lodash cloneDeep or see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would recommend you use the `find` function instead of filter to avoid the empty array return and undefined at `[0]`

Secondly, yes, the object reference would be returned. To avoid this, you can use `Object.assign({}, originalObject)` or using the spread syntax `{...originalObject}` . A potential problem would be with nested objects which could still be a problem. 
Probably this article can help you in such case https://medium.com/@Farzad_YZ/3-ways-to-clone-objects-in-javascript-f752d148054d